# iOS - Swift - Как словить ивент принятия SMS?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Как подписаться на событие прихода СМС от кого-либо и получить доступ к тексту самой СМС?

Comment: вот вообще никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По политике безопасности, у iOS приложений нет доступа к входящим SMS.

По крайней мере, такая возможность отсутствует в Public API. Можете использовать Private API, но тогда ваше приложение должны отклонить в AppStore.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16685